# Degree complement and using 那么

Tags: grammar, complement

I came up with this sentence below.

她哭得那么多了

Is it possible to put 那么 after 得?

多谢。

Comment: why not? (besides conj.)  那么 can function as adverb bkrs: I adv.
1) like that; in that way
2) about; or so
3) so; so very much
那么慢，得四个钟头才能到。 (We are) too slow, it will take about four hours to get there.
for more examples submit 得那么多 e.g. to iciba:

If you eat so much, you will get fat.

你要是吃得那么多, 是会发胖的.

2.

Why should you stuff yourself?

你为什么要吃得那么多 呢 ?

3.

He had made a thorough investigation. No wonder he knew so much about it.

他对此事做了彻底的调查, 怪不得他了解得那么多.

Comment: other possible complements （besides 得伤心，s. answer) of verb 哭: 得厉害、得断肠 （哭得累了）哭太多 exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 她哭得那么多了

You have misused the complement. We say:

> 她哭得那么伤心。
>
> 她哭得很厉害。

If you want to express *she has cried many times*, then you should say 她哭过很多次了.

So, your issue is 多了 isn't a correct complement for 哭. When you say 那么多了, you don't need 得. For example, we say 说(了)那么多了，we don't say 说得那么多了. 得 is just redundant here.